# Duda con if(...){fetch()...} else en Javascript

Tags: javascript, condiciones, fetch, async-await, else

Primero de todo disculpad si he formulado mal la pregunta o si estoy haciendo algo de manera incorrecta ya que es la primera vez que pregunto por aqui.

Mi consulta viene a raiz del siguiente código (ignorad si alguna cosa carece de sentido, es meramente de ejemplo):

```
condicion=false;

listaObjetos.foreach(objeto =>{
   if (condicion==false) {
      condicion=true;
      fetch('URL')
      .then(() => {
         array.push(respuesta);
      });
   }
   else {
      funcion(array);
   }
}
```

El problema es que al ser fetch una función asíncrona se ejecuta al final provocando que en las siguientes vueltas del foreach vaya por el else antes de que se añada la respuesta del fetch en el array ¿hay alguna manera de poder hacer que se ejecute el fetch de manera síncrona, o de que el else espere a que se ejecute el fetch? gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async function miFuncion() { //Definimos una función async
  let condicion = false;
  for (const objeto of listaObjetos) { //Utilizamos un ciclo for-of para poder usar async/await
    if (!condicion) {
      condicion = true;
      const respuesta = await fetch('URL');
      const data = await respuesta.json(); //Obtenemos los datos de la respuesta 
      array.push(data); //Agregamos los datos al arreglo
    } else {
      funcion(array); //Llamamos a la función con el arreglo
    }
  }
}
```

Es correcto, la función fetch es asíncrona y no nos garantiza que se complete antes de que se ejecute el código posterior. Para eso reemplazamos el `forEach` por un ciclo `for-of` para poder utilizar async/await. Dentro del ciclo, utilizamos `await` para esperar a que la promesa devuelta por fetch se resuelva antes de continuar con el resto del código.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me ha funcionado a la perfección